# Plot certain columns based on their name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns which looks like this.

```
date               A       B        C        D         E
1996-01-02  1.000000 1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   1.00000
1996-01-03  0.000950 0.00020  0.99975  1.00000   1.00007
1996-01-04 -0.005826 0.00020  1.00006  1.00046   1.00068
1996-01-05 -0.001587 0.00019  0.99962  0.99917   0.99853
1996-01-08  0.002821 0.00020  0.99878  0.99695   0.99493
1996-01-09 -0.014568 0.00020  0.99935  0.99801   0.99649
```

And I just want to plot certain columns, where the column names match up with the first x rownames of another df, which looks like this:

```
Row Name     Value
B        0.2455867
C        0.2117051
Z        0.2043087
M        0.1997719
A        0.1706845
```

For example, that I am able to choose that i just plot the first two, which gives me Columns B and C in a combined graph since the first two row names in the second df are B and C.

Comment: Not clear based on the description.   Do you want to extract the values from the first data

Comment: Yes and plot them column wise.
Maybe even in one graph and with the date column on the y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just subset the dataset based on the first two row.names

```
matplot(as.matrix(`row.names<-`(df1[intersect(names(df1), 
     row.names(df2))], df1$date)), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n', ylab = 'value')
axis(side = 1, at = seq_len(nrow(df1)), labels = df1$date)
```

---

Or convert to an `xts` object an plot

```
library(xts)
library(xtsExtra)
plot(xts(df1[intersect(names(df1), 
       row.names(df2))], order.by = as.Date(df1$date)), 
    main = 'plot', auto.legend = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("1996-01-02", "1996-01-03", "1996-01-04", 
"1996-01-05", "1996-01-08", "1996-01-09"), A = c(1, 0.00095, 
-0.005826, -0.001587, 0.002821, -0.014568), B = c(1, 2e-04, 2e-04, 
0.00019, 2e-04, 2e-04), C = c(1, 0.99975, 1.00006, 0.99962, 0.99878, 
0.99935), D = c(1, 1, 1.00046, 0.99917, 0.99695, 0.99801), E = c(1, 
1.00007, 1.00068, 0.99853, 0.99493, 0.99649)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(Value = c(0.24, 0.21, 0.2, 0.19, 0.17)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("B", 
"C", "Z", "M", "A"))
```

Comment: Thx.
Is it also possible to put this in one graph and plot it as line against the date?

Comment: @ITsMe You meant all the columns that match the row.names of second data?